# System.Web.Http missing in .net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, system.web.http

System.Web.Http is missing in my .net core 2.1 project.

the error states

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

please refer the image for more clarity

[image: Reference]

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2928

Comment: For 2.2 you need to install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package

Answer (score 6):

System.Web.Http is not available in dotnet core, but may be referenced by installing the following nuget package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim.dll.  This will clear the error.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.httperror?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http  equivalent for System.Web.Http?