# What is the ASP.NET Core 3.1 equivalent to HttpControllerContext and HttpActionContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have migrated the project from `Dot.Net-Framework 4.7.2` to `Asp.Net-Core 3.1`.
I want to change all property of ApiController Class in the WebApi.

```
public static HttpActionContext CreateActionContext(HttpControllerContext controllerContext = null, 
                                                    HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = null)
{
    HttpControllerContext context = controllerContext ?? CreateControllerContext();
    HttpActionDescriptor descriptor = actionDescriptor ?? CreateActionDescriptor();
    descriptor.ControllerDescriptor = context.ControllerDescriptor;
    return new HttpActionContext(context, descriptor);
}
```

For System.Web.Http, I followed the below link. When I used, it's working, but don't know whether is this right method and below one is not supported in MAC

[System.Web.Http missing in .net Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567384/system-web-http-missing-in-net-core-2-1)

Kindly provide any alternative or better solution

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? That is probably a better way to get an answer here - there may not be code that is directly translatable.

Comment: want to know what is equivalent to HttpControllerContext Class in Asp.Net Core 3.1.If  NetFramework there are so many properties under ApiController Class.so get to know property equivalent in ControllerBase class in Core 3.1

Comment: Yes, your question already says that - but it doesn't help.

Comment: @KarthicG Where are you accessing the context exactly? Describe what are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

In controllers and actions you can access the `HttpContext` using the property `HttpContext` by inheriting from the base class `ControllerBase`

While if you needed the `HttpContext` in other components you have to use dependency injection like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Then by injecting it in the constructor:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SomeClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
}
```

[MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1)